# SQL double join in python

Tags: python, mysql, join

i have two tables, a and b each with many rows. 
i have an SQL code saying

```
SELECT* FROM a INNER JOIN b ON (a.names = b.names) and (a.age = b.age)
```

im trying to make this in python using the .merge() function, and by making a mid-table from the first join and then trying to make it by joining that table to the next condition. but python pulls up an error

```
join3 = a.merge(b,how='inner',left_on = 'name', right_on = 'name')
join4 = join3.merge(b,how'inner',left_on='age',right_on='age')
```

this gives a memory error:
ive tried to replicate this using various & methods.
ive also tried this

```
merge = a.merge(b[b.age==a.age],left_on= 'name', right_on='name')
```

im at a lose to what to do

Comment: The above statement can also be written as `a.merge(b, how='inner', on=['name','age'])`. Should make some difference in memory used.

Comment: Yes thanks that did it i believe, just as a reference for others i couldnt use that formula as my columns had different names, but i just created a new column and called it the name i needed and have it equal to the other column, problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a.merge(b, how='inner', on=['name','age'])
```

and if say your column for ages in b had a different name say years, which mine did i did this

```
b['age'] = b['years']
```

and then i could use the above.
i also could have renamed that column but wanted to keep all original columns there